# Write a program that reads 5 integers from the user(TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting)

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that reads 5 integers from the user,the program should tell the user how many of these numbers are divisible by 5 and exit

I wonder why the program incurs that error, and I don't want the program to print 'Enter 5 integers' every time and just print 'Enter 5 integers' once

```
ints=[]
while True:
    n=input('Enter 5 integers\n')
    ints.append(n)
    if len(ints)==5:
        break
count=0
i=0
while i<len(ints):
    remain=ints[i]%5
    if remain==0:
        count+=1
    i+=1
print('{} of these ints are divisible by 5.'.format(count))
```

Expected result:

```
Enter 5 integers
5
10
22
34
25
3 of these integers are divisible by 5.
```

Actual results:

```
Enter 5 integers
5
Enter 5 integers
10
Enter 5 integers
22
Enter 5 integers
34
Enter 5 integers
25
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "5ints.py", line 10, in <module>
remain=ints[i]%5
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your input from strings to integers:

```
n=int(input('Enter 5 integers\n'))
```

Without that, when you do:

```
remain=ints[i]%5
```

The `%` operator is applied to a `str` object, which is the formatting function - and that's where the error is coming from.

To make the prompt for input come only once:

```
ints=[]
print('Enter 5 integers: ')
while True:
    n=int(input())
    ints.append(n)
    if len(ints)==5:
        break
```

Comment: Ok, but how to let the program only print 'Enter 5 integers' once? The program print 'Enter 5 integer' every time once I input an integer.

Comment: @Eric Added that to the answer as well.